# Creating Pivot Footers on Windows phone 7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I know that pivot control of windows phone has two parts pivot headers and pivot item control.

what i want to display is, pivot headers below the pivot item control (or pivot footers).

But i found this this thing is not available in pivot control.

Is there any other way, to display tabs at the footer of wp7 app.

thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own style for Pivot control. The easiest way to move header down is create a copy of default Pivot style and slightly modify it.

```
    <Style x:Key="PivotStyle" TargetType="controls:Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Pivot">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Margin="24,17,0,-7"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <controlsPrimitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

`<controls:Pivot Title="pivot" Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle}">`

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution. You need to inherit from `Pivot` control and switch headers row with items row:

```
  public class PivotFooter : Pivot
  {
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
      base.OnApplyTemplate();

      var headers = base.GetTemplateChild("HeadersListElement") as PivotHeadersControl;
      var items = base.GetTemplateChild("PivotItemPresenter") as ItemsPresenter;

      var grid = headers.Parent as Grid;
      if(grid != null)
      {
        var firstHeight = grid.RowDefinitions[1].Height;
        var secondHeight = grid.RowDefinitions[2].Height;

        grid.RowDefinitions[1].Height = secondHeight;
        grid.RowDefinitions[2].Height = firstHeight;    
      }

      headers.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 2);
      items.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
    }
  }
```