# Windows Phone 7 panorama item with no header

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, layout, margin, panorama-control

I would like to create a PanoramaItem that has no header at all. I would like to place some controls in this PanoramaItem and I want them to occupy the whole space. Of course I was able to delete the header text and change the font to smaller, but still there are some margins left. This might be easy, but I am new to WP7 development...

Is it possible to achieve and how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Negative top margin may be the quickest way to get rid the stubborn header padding.

```
   <controls:Panorama Margin="0,-25,0,0">
   </controls:Panorama>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify Styles of Panorama. There is was a question recently for Pivot here: [Creating Pivot Footers on Windows phone 7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061965/creating-pivot-footers-on-windows-phone-7-application/8062966#8062966), but you can do the same with a Panorama

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to make a new style by inheriting a default style and just changing the margins or sth?

Comment: Yes. Just remove the Header block and adjust Item to fill the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<phone:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock FontSize="1"/>
     </DataTemplate>
</phone:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
```

it's a very funny method but for WP 8.1 Silverlight Apps this works fine.