# how to let panorama control not show Model class name

Tags: windows-phone-7, templates, model, header, panorama-control

I'm binding Panorama control to my view model (of type `ObservableCollection`).

I use `ItemTemplate`. I can't use `HeaderTemplate` because it makes transition not really smooth (don't know why !! )
Here is my XAML

```
<controls:Panorama Name="panorama" >
                        <controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="210"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Panorama>
```

However, when running, every panorama item **does show  the Model class name**. 
If I use `HeaderTemplate`, it doesnot show that.
How to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's bind on an ObservableCollection property of your ViewModel something's missing.
Your Panorama control should have an `ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}">`

If your itemSource is set in the code behing, the quickest way is to set a negative margin to hide your header...

```
<controls:Panorama Margin="0,-20,0,0">
</controls:Panorama>
```

Or if you want something a little bit cleaner you can modify your styles for panorama and supress the header...
This is [Creating Pivot Footers on Windows phone 7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061965/creating-pivot-footers-on-windows-phone-7-application/8062966#8062966) it works the same way for panorama control

Comment: thanks, I set ItemsSource in code behind, the ItemTemplate is OK. The problem is when I don't set HeaderTemplate, each panorama item shows my Model class name !

Comment: OK it's because you supress HeaderTemplate that it displays your model class name. The class name is displayed instead of the header ? Or instead of `Name`

Comment: The classname is display instead of the header. A more strange is that when I set ItemTemplate header="aaa". It both show "aaa" and Class name !!

Comment: Okay I've edit my answer, it'ss what you were looking for?
I don't know why that behave like this but you can hide it or supress it...

Comment: the only way to hide it or suppress it is to handle HeaderTemplate. But whenever HeaderTemplate is handled, the panorama swiping is not smooth anymore

Comment: Hi @entropy I am experiencing the same problem. I read the above comments but couldnt make out whats the exact solution. Can u explain what steps helped u in removing the Class name from header.